# How to take an image from html table row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I face a problem, I can take the values from HTML table row and I can easily set them to another text box, but how we can take an image from HTML table row and how to set that into a div, 
Summarize: I want to take an image from HTML Table row and set that to a div.

```
// For View data 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dtBasicExample tbody").on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $("#txtSelect").text("1 row selected");
    var rowData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    $("#txtSId").val(rowData[0]);
    $("#txtSName").val(rowData[1]);
    $("#txtSPosition").val(rowData[2]);
    $("#imgS").html(`<a href="#"><img src="images/'.rowData[3].'"></a>`);
    $("#txtSFacebook").val(rowData[4]);
    $("#txtSTwitter").val(rowData[5]);
    $("#txtSGoogleplus").val(rowData[6]);
  });
});
```

Comment: check your ` and '

Answer (score 0):

You should rather be doing :

```
$("#imgS").html('<a href="#"><img src="images/'+rowData[3]+'"></a>');
```

To concatenate in JS you need to use `+` and not  `.`

You also need to use the character `'` at the start and end of your string rather than using `

Comment: Tnx from your answer, but no result it doesn't show the image

Comment: @Ahmad does the `images` folder exist in the same directory as the current file? As it [should work](https://jsfiddle.net/hvjtmz0p/) if `images/'+rowData[3]` is a valid file.

Comment: Yes, images folder have existed, but I don't know why it doesn't display, and one thing more #imgS is the id of that div which I want to take the image from table row and to display it.